# Approximate String Searching in Java (allowing characters to match more than one option)

Tags: java, string

I have a BNDM search algorithm in java currently but I want to adapt it such that the letter "N" matches any other letter. For example, the string: "NATG" should match "CATG". I am creating a software for nucleotide matching so the sequences will be only A,G,T,C,N where N is any A,G,T,C.

For example: If Sequence: "ATGCN"  and Source: "ATGATGAATGCC". The program should return the index range of the source that matches the sequence. In this case, 7-11. Also if it matches several times, it should print each match. Since the source is often a thousand characters long, I wish to implement a fast searching algorithm. Below is my current BNDM code however this only allows exact matches.

I am not sure if the BNDM algorithm below can be adapted to do this. I am open to a different search algorithm.

I have attached the code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BNDM {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 5;
    String source,pattern;
    System.out.print("Enter sequence:");
    pattern = sc.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("Enter source:");
    source= sc.nextLine(); 


    if (pattern.length() == source.length() && pattern.equals(source)) 
    {
        System.out.println("Sequence = Source");
    }

    char[] x = pattern.toCharArray(), y = source.toCharArray();
    int i, j, s, d, last, m = x.length, n = y.length;
    int[] b = new int[65536];

    /* Pre processing */
    for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = 0;
    }
    s = 1;
    for (i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        b[x[i]] |= s;
        s <<= 1;
    }

    /* Searching phase */
    j = 0;
    while (j <= n - m) {
        i = m - 1;
        last = m;
        d = ~0;
        while (i >= 0 && d != 0) {
            d &= b[y[j + i]];
            i--;
            if (d != 0) {
                if (i >= 0) {
                    last = i + 1;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sequence in Source starting at 
                    position:");
                    System.out.println(j);
                    System.out.println("Sequence:");
                    System.out.println(pattern);
                    System.out.println("Source:");
                    System.out.println(source.substring(j,j+m));

                }
            }
            d <<= 1;
        }
        j += last;
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to match overlapping matches as well? For example, if I have `AA` as the pattern and `AAAA` as the nucleotides, do you want 3 matches or 2?

Comment: I am not sure which I will need to use. How would the algorithm change?

Comment: The regex will be more complex if you want to match overlaps. The code you showed matches overlaps. My answer doesn't.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am sorry, I am new to Java but when I compile, it returns error "cannot find symbol" for Pattern and Matcher

Comment: See the edit. You just need to import some stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of matching can be easily done with regexes:

```
// remember to add these at the top:
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;



String pattern = "ATGCN";
String nucleotides = "ATGATGAATGCC";

// first convert the pattern into a proper regex
// i.e. replacing any N with [ATCG]
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern.replaceAll("N", "[ATCG]"));

// create a Matcher to find everywhere that the pattern matches
Matcher m = regex.matcher(nucleotides);

// find all the matches
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match found:");
    System.out.println("start:" + m.start());
    System.out.println("end:" + (m.end() - 1)); // minus 1 here because the end of a regex match is always off by 1
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Match {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String origin = in.next();
    String match = in.next();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(match.replaceAll("N", "(A|G|T|C)"));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(origin);
    while (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.start() + "-" + (matcher.end() - 1));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Would a similar program be able to handle possible insertions? Basically, allow the sequence AGTC* match both AGTC and AGTCA where is * is a possible one base insertion.

Comment: If you delete 'N's from the string having 'N' characters, then it is possible to find the matches but if the string gets longer it would become impossible to do so. Another strategy would be replacing 'N's with 'A', 'G', 'T', or 'C' which for k number of 'N's would cost you about (4^k) times running a loop